# Join two elements as a tuple, which can be a tuple themselved or not

Tags: python, tuples

Strange title, but easy to ask with an example:

```
mytuple = (1, 2)
mynumber = 3
print (mynumber,) + (mytuple,)
>> (3, (1, 2))
```

I don't want a tuple inside a tuple. I expect getting (3, 1, 2). Any idea?

Comment: `(mynumber,) + mytuple`?

Comment: @thefourtheye A typo, sorry. I obviously meant mynumber. Not many variables to choose in such a small code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check whether second object is a tuple:

```
a = (1, 2)
b = 3
joined = (a if isinstance(a, tuple) else (a,)) + (b if isinstance(b, tuple) else (b,))
```

Comment: Any chanceof keeping it simpler? I'm using it for a lambda expression, and this may work, but will be a damn big lambda

Comment: Nope, all you can do is to replace conditional expression with lambda function (see another answer). But you cant make it simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
mytuple = (1, 2)
mynumber = 3
print (mynumber,)+mytuple
```

Comment: may be you didn't see that the example given by the op is an example?

Comment: also you even succeeded to actually not get the expected result. amazing

Comment: my point is that this is a particular case, given by the op as an *example*. I suggest you read the title of the question again

Answer (score 0):

you can use a lambda to get tuple out of anything:

```
always_tuple = lambda x: x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x,)

joined = always_tuple(a) + always_tuple(b)
```